# Regex to match both float and scientific notation

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match strings that look something like:

`{"1": [123, 456, 789], "time": 1.234e-05}`

or

`{"1": [123, 456, 789], "time": 1.234}`

Here is what I have:

`\{"1": \[123, 456, 789], "time": [0-9.]*}`

While this Regex matches the second string that has a float on `time`, it would fail to catch scientific notation with `e-...`. How should I change my Regex to match both?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/CAv5BD/1

Comment: What is your expected results.

Comment: Why are you using regex to parse/match JSON content?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's a stringified JSON in my case

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9.]*(e\-[0-9]*)?`

`.e-` matches a single character in the list `.e-` (case sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one or zero quantifier `?`:

```py
>>> re.match('(\d+\.\d+(e-\d+)?)', '1.234').group(1)
'1.234'
>>> re.match('(\d+\.\d+(e-\d+)?)', '1.234e-05').group(1)
'1.234e-05'
```